# Updating data to integrate it in my datawarehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, ssis-2008

I received sales data from a client to integrate it into his datawarehouse. Normally there are two columns to define a sales row - `num_transcation` and `num_line_transaction`. But I received a lot of rows with the same `num_transcation` and `num_line_transaction` so when I execute this query:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ll_vente_num_transaction, ll_vente_num_ligne_transaction 
                           order by ll_vente_num_transaction) rn, * 
     from my_table) t
where 
    rn > 2
```

I get almost 43000 rows with the same identity (`num_transcation` and `num_line_transaction`) and the only thing that differs those rows is the sales date.

I need a way to update "num_line_transaction" to be able to load the data in the datawarhouse, otherwise it will load only one row of every "num_transcation" and "num_line_transaction" combination.

For example:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------+
| NUM_TRANSACTION | NUM_LIGNE_TRANSACTION |
+-----------------+-----------------------+
|       106969796 |               3148291 |
|       106969796 |               3148291 |
|       106969796 |               3148291 |
|       106969796 |               3148291 |
|       106969796 |               3148291 |
|       106969796 |               3148291 |
|       106969796 |               3148291 |
+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

I need to update those rows to become:

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+
| NUM_TRANSACTION |   NUM_LIGNE_TRANSACTION |
+-----------------+-------------------------+
|       106969796 |                 3148291 |
|       106969796 |                 3148292 |
|       106969796 |                 3148293 |
|       106969796 |                 3148294 |
|       106969796 |                 3148295 |
|       106969796 |                 3148296 |
|       106969796 |                 3148297 |
+-----------------+-------------------------+
```

Please, any idea will be appreciated. I'm stuck here.

Comment: @Dan Guzman are you sure about the editing which seperates `NUM_LIGNE_TRANSACTION` into two columns?

Comment: opps, that was a misclick, they should be in NUM_LIGNE_TRANSACTION

Comment: @yassinesaddi, please review my edit to make sure the data are correct and fix as necessary.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, thanks for the catch. The tabs weren't consistent in the original text and I neglected to clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a distinguishing (unique column such as `sales_date` as you mentioned ), the following statement will help :

```
with t2 as
(
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by num_transaction order by num_ligne_transaction)+
       num_ligne_transaction - 1
        as rn 
 from tab t
)
update t1
   set t1.num_ligne_transaction = t2.rn
  from tab t1
  join t2
    on t1.num_transaction = t1.num_transaction
   and t1.sales_date = t2.sales_date;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9df10b1be4a697102a0801e3a06a3c8)</kbd>

Comment: Thank u so much, i had to change the join clause but it helped me a lot.